# Fitting pgfplots inside margins when using minpage

Tags: pgfplots, minipage

I have the following code.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % utf8 characters
%\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}            % math packages
\usepackage{amsfonts}   
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}            % SI units
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}     % TikZ 
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}           % links and hyperrefs
\usepackage{geometry}           % document size 
\usepackage{float, newfloat}    % floating environements
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}   % footnotes bottom fix
\usepackage{tocbibind}          % extra items to toc    
\usepackage{listings}           % listings  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}           % headers and footers   
\usepackage{standalone}         
\usepackage{emptypage}          % no numbers on empty pages
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{booktabs}           % tables
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{glossaries}         % glossaries
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

The second definition does not distinguish between the cell's short-circuit power and the component of switching power that is being dissipated internally to the cell as a result of the drain-to-substrate capacitance that is being charged and discharged. In this definition, the interconnect switching power is the power dissipated because of lumped wire capacitance and input pin capacitances but not because of the output pin capacitance.
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (0,0) node[left] {$V\subb{in}$} --++ (1,0) coordinate (e) --++ (0,-1) --++ (1,0) node[nmos, anchor=G] (nmos) {}
            (e) to[short,*-] ++ (0, 1) --++ (1,0) node[pmos, anchor=G] (pmos) {} (pmos.D) -- (nmos.D) (nmos.S) node[ground]{} (pmos.S) node[vcc]{}
            ($(nmos.D)!0.5!(pmos.D)$)  coordinate (out) to[short,*-] ++(1,0) node[right] {$V\subb{out}$};
%           (out)++(1,0) coordinate(en) to[C,*-,l=$C\subb{L}$] (en|-nmos.S) node[ground]{};
            \draw[-latex](pmos.S)++(.2,0) coordinate(ne) -- (ne|-pmos.D) node[midway,right] {$I\subb{DD}$};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[
                    width=\linewidth,
                    trim axis left, trim axis right,
                    xlabel=$t / \si{\nano\second}$,ylabel=$\si{\volt}$,
                    grid=both, minor tick num = 2,
                    axis y line*=left,
                    minor grid style = {dashed},
                    no markers,
                ]
                \addplot[blue,  thick] table[x index=0, y index=1,col sep= comma] {inversor_waveforms.data};%
                \label{p1}\addlegendentry{$V\subb{in}$}
                \addplot[red,   thick] table[x index=0, y index=2,col sep= comma] {inversor_waveforms.data};%
                \label{p2}\addlegendentry{$V\subb{out}$}            
                \end{axis}          
                \begin{axis}[
                    width=\linewidth,
    %               xlabel=$t/\si{\second}$,
                    ylabel=$\si{\nano\ampere}$,
                    axis y line*=right,
                    axis x line=none,
                    no markers,
                ]
                \addlegendimage{blue,thick}\addlegendentry{$V\subb{in}$}
                \addlegendimage{red, thick}\addlegendentry{$V\subb{out}$}
                \addplot[color=green!75!black,  thick] table[x index=0, y index=3,col sep= comma] {inversor_waveforms.data};\addlegendentry{$I\subb{DD}$}
                \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{minipage}
    \caption{CMOS inversor with voltage and current waveforms}
    \label{fig:inversor_ex}
    \end{figure}
    \hrule
    A simple example of short-circuit power can be seen in Figure \ref{fig:inversor_ex}. When the input voltage starts to fall the P-transistor begins to conduct while the N-transistor is transitioning between ohmic and cutoff region. The coexistence of the two partially-conducting transistors creates a direct path between \vdd\ and GND and thus consuming power. This effect is included in both definitions for internal power.
\end{document}
```

which gives me this output.
[image]
How can I get the plot to fit inside the margins?

Comment: you should provide complete but short document that we can test why happens this what you reported. probably `minipage` width is smaller than image width,

Comment: your problem probably source i your code line  problem probably lie in code line `trim axis left, trim axis right`, but unfortunately i cant test this since you not provide mwe.

Comment: I added the full MWE. And trimming the axis dosnt change the ouput.

Comment: where is defined `\subb`?

Comment: for `trim axis left, trim axis right` i said "probably" (i can't check this since your mwe is not complete and data tables are not available). otherwise, @koleygr provide generic solution.

Answer (score 1):

The most common solutions and my suggestion (described inside the document):

PS: Also, minipages are not really needed in your MWE and not at mine too, but my answer is created to use minipages too (if you really need them for any reason). If you don't use minipages, some lengths has to changed like (\linewidth->0.5\linewidth etc)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\section{The source of the problem}

As you can see in figure~\ref{fig:1} there is no blue border for the left part of the image 
\begin{figure}[!htb]
        \centering
        \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \path[draw,ultra thick,blue,fill=green] (0,0)rectangle(7,3)
            node[pos=0.5]{Text};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[fill=red] (0,0)rectangle(7,6);
                \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{minipage}
    \caption{CMOS inversor with voltage and current waveforms}
    \label{fig:1}
    \end{figure}

    If we reduce the width of the left image to 6 (instead 7 ) units:
\begin{figure}[!htb]
        \centering
        \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[ultra thick,blue,fill=green] (0,0)rectangle(6,3)
            node[pos=0.5]{Text};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[fill=red] (0,0)rectangle(7,6);
                \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{minipage}
    \caption{CMOS inversor with voltage and current waveforms}
    \label{fig:2}
    \end{figure}

This means that our image extends out of minipage, that its role is not to prevent "overflowing" of its content.
\pagebreak
\section{Common solutions}

\subsection{Scaling}

 Scale the tikzpicture (see ~\ref{fig:3}):

\begin{figure}[!htb]
        \centering
        \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale={6/7}]
            \draw[ultra thick,blue,fill=green] (0,0)rectangle(7,3)
            node[pos=0.5]{Text};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[fill=red] (0,0)rectangle(7,6);
                \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{minipage}
    \caption{CMOS inversor with voltage and current waveforms}
    \label{fig:3}
    \end{figure}

        Advantages:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Text inside tikzpicture with original sizes 
    \end{itemize}

        Disadvantages:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Need to scale every tikzpicture with separate scale number.
    \end{itemize}
\pagebreak
\subsection{The ``adjustbox''}
 Place the tikzpicture inside an adjustbox:

\begin{figure}[!htb]
        \centering
        \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}\begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[ultra thick,blue,fill=green] (0,0)rectangle(7,3)
            node[pos=0.5]{Text};;
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{adjustbox}
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[fill=red] (0,0)rectangle(7,6);
                \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{minipage}
    \caption{CMOS inversor with voltage and current waveforms}
    \label{fig:4}
    \end{figure}

    Advantages:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Automating scale for every possibly picture
    \end{itemize}

        Disadvantages:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Text is scaled too and picture fontsizes doesn't match text fontsize
        \item Usage of the extra package ``adjustbox''
    \end{itemize}

\pagebreak
\section{Suggests}
\subsection{In case of known maximum and minimum x coordinate}

{\bfseries Define a maximum x to be \verb|\linewidth| and use it as your basic unit}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
        \centering
        \begin{minipage}[inner sep=0]{.5\linewidth}
\centering
%Defining maximum x to be \linewidth:
\def\maxx{0.95\linewidth} %Reduced because of the thick width of
% the blue lines added an the result (Can be calculated, but also shows the mentioned disadvantages)
\begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[ultra thick,blue,fill=green] (0,0)rectangle(\maxx,{3/7*\maxx})
            node[pos=0.5]{Text};;
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[fill=red] (0,0)rectangle(7,6);
                \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{minipage}
    \caption{CMOS inversor with voltage and current waveforms}
    \label{fig:5}
    \end{figure}

    Advantages:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Everything is automated in your tikzpicture and canm be used in any document, any scale, any size etc.
        \item You can use the same idea for ymax and can transform the whole tikzpicture (plus xscale and yscale) with perfect results.
        \item Need more effort :P (Don't ask, I Used to teach)
    \end{itemize}

        Disadvantages:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Need more time.
        \item Some times it is too complicated and may be ``impposible''.
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: i wouldn't recommended use of `adjustbox`. better is make correction at the source of problem. i have the solution, however i cant test it since op didn't provide needed information (missed are relevant document preamble with all her/his command and styles definitions). see my second comment below question.

Comment: @Zarko It say final report on the title. You really don't want that preamble :) Besides subcaption already has these implemented so no need to trim or playing around with minipages

Comment: @Zarko, thanks, I didn't suggested adjustbox too, I just added some fixes... Now I added my suggestion too.

Comment: I feel more comforable changing the with to .8\linewidth inside axis configuration. But it does not result in any change.

Comment: @jagjordi, my answer is generic for tikzpictures... And of course this is an option too (your way). And possibly better than mine because of the nature of pgfplots (labels and axis names are not easy to used inside my way).  Possibly my answer had to be in another post and doesn't really help with your problem. It just answering about the source of it.